# How to plot a point on a time series in python

Tags: python, plot, time-series, datetime-format

I am facing an issue with plotting points in a time series since I cannot identify the y-axis value. I have 2 datasets: one NetCDF file with satellite data (sea surface temperature), and another CSV file with storm track data (time, longitude, latitude, wind speed, etc.). I can plot the desired temperature time series for all storm track locations located in the ocean. However, I want to indicate the time of the storm footprint occurrence within each time series line. So, one line represents one location and the changing temperature over time, but I also want to show WHEN the storm occurred at that location.

This is my code so far (it works):

```
lati = stormtrack_lat.values
loni = stormtrack_lon.values

for i, dummy in enumerate(lati):
    dsloc = SSTskin_file.sel(lon=loni[i], lat=lati[i], method='nearest')
    dsloc['analysed_sst'].plot()
    #plt.plot(dsloc,stormtrack_time[i], "or") #here I want to add one point to each line indicating the time when the storm occured at this location
plt.title('My title')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('SST skin in K')
```

[image: blah]

The netcdf file contains the time data as datetime coordinate, but my CSV file contains this data:

```
|    da   | INDEX | SIZE  |  AREA     |   x     |  y |  RADIUS   |  MEANV

2020021018  1505    2934    177.363     -2.82   49.87   1782.18     16.18

2020021100  1505    3812    220.078     5.25    49.57   2811.51     16.17
...
```

where 'da' represents the date and time (YYYYMMDDHH). So, I think I need to (1) convert the CSV 'da' values into a datetime format in order to use them for the line `plt.plot(dsloc,stormtrack_time[i], "or")` and then (2) to find those datetime values within the netcdf file and then (3) use than time point for plotting the corresping SST value/time point.

The problem is that I do not know HOW to do this. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to do this:

```
lati = stormtrack_lat.values
loni = stormtrack_lon.values
timei = stormtrack_datetime.values

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20), dpi=300)

for i, dummy in enumerate(lati):
    dsloc = SSTskin_file.sel(lon=loni[i], lat=lati[i], method='nearest')
    dstime = SSTskin_file.sel(time=timei[i], lon=loni[i], lat=lati[i], method='nearest')
    skin_celsius = (dsloc['analysed_sst']) - 273.15
    timesteps = dsloc.time.values
    timestep = dstime.time.values
    timevalue = ((dstime['analysed_sst']).values) - 273.15
    lineplot = plt.plot(timesteps, skin_celsius )
    dotplot = plt.plot(timestep, timevalue, "or") 
plt.title('Skin SST over time at storm track locations',  fontsize = 20 )
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel('Skin SST in $^{\circ}C$',  fontsize = 16)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 16)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 16)
#plt.legend(lineplot) #Here I would like to plot the legend for the line plots (time series data). I want to indicate the location (longitude and latitude) of the time series
plt.legend(dotplot[:1], ['Storm track at location and time'], fontsize = 16);
fig2.savefig('SSTskin_storm_timeseries_test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: new plot]